# Wallpaper and Polyurethane Insulation board

Tags: insulation, wallpaper

My room has been insulated with Polyurethane Insulation board and I’ve no idea if you can put wallpaper directly on top or not? If not then what can I do? I don’t like the silver spaceship vibe I’ve got going on.

Comment: You could put wallpaper on that board, however it is unusual for the poly to be on the outside of the wall. Usually it is covered with drywall.  Maybe more info about your particular situation, ( Why it is not covered with drywall) and a pic or 2.

Comment: If you mean the foam board is currently exposed... That may not meet fire codes. Usually a firebreak is required. Plasterboard is the usual choice, but I'm told 1/2" plywood may be acceptable; doublecheck with your Local Authority Having Jurisdiction, aka town inspector's office or equivalent.

Comment: Is this a rental or owned property? If it's a rental, you'll definitely have to clear any decorations like wall paper or paint with the property owner/management.